# Why is the isTrusted property in compositionend event always set to false on Chrome?

Tags: html, dom-events

Playground: https://jsfiddle.net/gggtt/a7rc8654/5/

You can trigger composition events by using (Japanese) IME on Windows or ChromeOS with spellcheck enabled. Once I finish the composition, I get the `CompositionEvent` as follows:

[image: compositionend event console log]

Note that the `isTrusted` property is false. Why is that?

I am seeing this behavior on Chrome Beta v106 with Guest Profile.
On Firefox v104, the `isTrusted` property is correctly set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is https://crbug.com/1038569 which you can star in the hope it gets some love from Chrome devs.